# Fetching data from firebase, Screen shows blank after executing in android

Tags: java, android

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
   private FirebaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataClass>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"), DataClass.class)
                        .build();
        mAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(options);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

FirebaseAdapter

```
public class FirebaseAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataClass,FirebaseAdapter.MyviewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseAdapter";
    public FirebaseAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataClass model) {
      holder.name.setText(model.getName());
      holder.age.setText(model.getAge());
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Now Bind method executing");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v=  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_represent,parent,false);
        MyviewHolder v1 = new MyviewHolder(v);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: Now on create method executing");
        return v1;
    }
    
    public static class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView age;
        public MyviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.names);
            age = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        }
    }
}
```

DataClass

```
public class DataClass {

    private  String name;
       private String age;

       public DataClass(){

       }

    public DataClass(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}



 doubt in this parts
     public DataClass(String name, String age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
            }
          protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataClass model) {
              holder.name.setText(model.getName());
              holder.age.setText(model.getAge());
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Now Bind method executing");
            }
because showing me that constructor never used
```

I'm not getting any errors but still my screen shows empty, Actually it is displaying null data
how to find it and guys tell me how to solve this issue
I know I made small mistake somewhere in this code help me to rectify it
Thank you.............................................

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

From

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

To

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Hope this work.

Comment: Also Try Checking your firebase Security Rules and Allow to read by Setting Value as aTrue if its default false.

Comment: It's not working bro, can you find it ? is my code correct?

Comment: @MadhanMohan please attach your firebase child node structure. it seems your code is right.

Comment: Bro I got that one, can you please tell me this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990161/how-to-search-using-lowercase-in-firebaserecycleroptions-in-android-java

Answer (score -2):

do u have any messages in firebase database or its empty?

you can add some messages through firebase so you can check it